# Angular 2+ - ng-content as an attribute value in the template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have component that looks something like this:

```
<text-field name=myusername>Username</text-field>
```

I'd like to place "Username" in the placeholder attribute of an input, kind of like this:

```
<input name={{name}} placeholder="{{ng-content}}">
```

Of course, the above doesnt work but I was wondering if there is a way to put the ng-content in an attribute?

here is my test plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/gk0Y6IQGXyk4gJz5EjV4?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that won't work. The only way to display the content is using:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

You are trying to use a different kind of `@Input`, and to keep everything semantically the same obtaining such kind of 'input' is not supported. Just use an attribute and an `@Input` in your component

Answer (score 4):

Of course there are workarounds, like the one I created in an adaptation of your plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/c7XEgIDiFchjMjzVmyBF?p=preview

```
<span style="display: none;" #text><ng-content></ng-content></span>
<input name={{name}} placeholder="{{text.innerHTML}}">
```

Use a hidden span to contain  the content and use that as value for your placeholder.